# Saving tab bar items order and coming back to them when re-launching app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am a beginner in coding and am writing an app that uses UITabBarController in Xcode 4 I used the default template of course. Looking at [this code](http://github.com/Ge0rges/IC-Beirut/)  how would I save the order of the tab bar items after the user has re-arranged them and load them back when the user launches the app? and also how would I make it so that when app launches the user is taken to the last view he saw before closing the app previously? thanks a lot!

Comment: There are many files in the GitHub project provided in the link. Can you point us to specific classes or code blocks that are relevant to your question?

Comment: It looks like the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/Ge0rges/IC-Beirut/blob/master/IC%20Beirut/AppDelegate.m) in the linked project already has some code attempting to modify the order of tab bar items and set the initial view controller based on `NSUserDefaults`. Can you provide more details about what is or is not working?

Comment: Well there is no specific class or block of code... I did not try this in any way , I did before but removed the code and came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nsuserdefaults to save or any other source you want but here is the code from [UITabBarController: switch to a different view controller programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095471/uitabbarcontroller-switch-to-a-different-view-controller-programmatically)

```
if ([[WSFUserDefaults sharedInstance] savedTabBarLocation] > 0) {

        if ([[WSFUserDefaults sharedInstance] savedTabBarLocation] > 3) {
            UIViewController *selectViewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[[WSFUserDefaults sharedInstance] savedTabBarLocation]];
            [tabBarController setSelectedViewController:tabBarController.moreNavigationController];
            [tabBarController.moreNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];//make sure we're at the top level More
            [tabBarController.moreNavigationController pushViewController:selectViewController animated:NO];
        }
        else {
            [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:[[WSFUserDefaults sharedInstance] savedTabBarLocation]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: HOw would I save the order in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: SO this code is for switching views programaticaly?

Comment: google buddy... i type in save nsmutablearray in and brought me right to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143039/save-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults with some slight tweaking between that code and this you should have what you need in 10 minutes